# Why are these nested Bootstrap rows not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a two level nested Bootstrap rows within one Bootstrap column. I've commented in the code which ones work and which ones does not. In the cases where I want each to only be 6 in the nested rows, it shows up as 6, but the next column doesn't fill up the other 6 and instead wraps underneath it. In each case, there are never two columns showing. It's tough to describe Bootstrap problems and the site is not published so I can't show it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-9"> <!--this works-->
            <div class="iframe-container">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/23912696" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3"> <!--this works-->
            <row>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-12"> <!--this doesn't work-->
                    <row>
                        <div class="col-6"><img src="images/plasticSurgery.jpg" class="thumb" /></div><!--this doesn't work-->
                        <div class="col-6 thumbP">Plastic Surgery</div><!--this doesn't work-->
                        <div class="col-6"><img src="images/plasticSurgery.jpg" class="thumb" /></div><!--this doesn't work-->
                        <div class="col-6 thumbP">Plastic Surgery Dr</div><!--this doesn't work-->
                    </row>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-12"> <!--this doesn't work-->
                    <row>
                        <div class="col-6"><img src="images/plasticSurgery.jpg" class="thumb" /></div> <!--this doesn't work-->
                        <div class="col-6 thumbP">Plastic Surgery</div> <!--this doesn't work-->
                        <div class="col-6"><img src="images/plasticSurgery.jpg" class="thumb" /></div> <!--this doesn't work-->
                        <div class="col-6 thumbP">Plastic Surgery</div> <!--this doesn't work-->
                    </row>
                </div>
            </row>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<row>
```

Is not a valid HTML element. Maybe you should change it with:

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

It is the Bootstrap way of defining row containers.

Comment: Yes, I had that correct on the outer row, but not the inner ones. Darn typo. Been looking at the code for too long. Thanks